# google-cloud-datacatalog 0.8.0 is missing TagTemplate option

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-data-catalog

I am working on developing a datacatalog integration pipeline in google cloud composer. Since I am using composer version composer-1.12.4-airflow-1.10.10, its not allowing me to install google-cloud-datacatalog version 3 or above at the same time its allowing only 0.8.0 or below. This is because an internal conflict. When I tried to use version 0.8.0, while creating TagTemplate object, its giving a **TagTemplate** Not Found exception. So I am left with an option to upgrade the composer, which is very difficult at this point, since I need to test the compatibility of more than 200 existing pipelines. Is there any other option programatically I can tackle this using the 0.8.0 version.

Here is an excerpt of my module:

```
from google.cloud import datacatalog
        
dc_client = datacatalog.DataCatalogClient()
tag_template = datacatalog.TagTemplate() <Here is I am getting the not found error>
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to take a look in the Cloud Build history to understand the version conflicts when you try to install a more recent version of the library and try to resolve them if possible (by specifying the versions of other libraries too)

Comment: According to [this thread](https://github.com/googleapis/python-datacatalog/issues/84#issue-771758031), there is a way to create a tag template using a dictionary. Would that help you? Also, I saw that Google updated [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176555227) Feature Request where it is stated that DataCatalog version 3 is only supported by composer version 1.15.2 or higher.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes it showing a complex way of doing that. If I go with that approach I ma y have to do a considerable refactoring while updating datacatalog version later

Comment: @itroulli I have checked it and understood its conflicting with an internal dependency of google-cpi-core library. Since its not in my control I can't specify the version there.

Comment: @MIHaque this is usually happening because the pre-installed google client libraries are on older versions which depend on an older version of `google-api-core` as well. So since `google-cloud-datacatalog` needs a more recent version, it fails. However, if you install new versions of all these libraries you may avoid the conflict. Unfortunately, the only way to battle this (apart from upgrading composer) is by trial and error and I don't have a 1.12.4 environment available atm. Similar, past answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60652701/7903159, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472299/7903159